# Updating a field's change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing simple jQuery script for updating one field on another field's change. It's working, but I'm trying to write good code and use best practices. Can you please tell me what my mistakes and 'bad' things in this code?

Maybe I should use `getTotalUserScore()` in `updateTotalUserScore()`, not in $('.js-question-score').change() function, or I shouldn't use 2 functions for so simple piece of logic, or my variables names are bad. Tell me anything you feel about this code. Also, I've realized that my total-score field sometimes updates with delay.

```js
$('.js-question-score').change(function () {
    var totalScore = getTotalUserScore();
    updateTotalUserScore(totalScore);
});

function updateTotalUserScore(totalScore) {
    $('.js-total-user-score').text(totalScore)
}

function getTotalUserScore() {
    var totalScore = 0;
    $('.js-question-score').each(function() {
        totalScore += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    return totalScore;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form> 
  <input class="js-question-score" name="first" min="0" max="20"  value="0" type="number"/>
  <input class="js-question-score" name="second" min="0" max="20"  value="0" type="number"/>
  <input class="js-question-score" name="third" min="0" max="20"  value="0" type="number"/>
</form>

<div>
  User total score:
  <span class="js-total-user-score">
    0
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: best practice is don't repeat yourself (DRY) so chache the variable

Comment: @EaBangalore do you mean writing smth like  "var scoreInputs = $('.js-question-score')" at the beginning of the script?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in only one event. Get sums of all value on each changement like this :

```js
$(".js-question-score").change(function(){
  var res=0;
  $(".js-question-score").each(function()
  {
    res+=parseInt($(this).val());
  });
   $(".js-total-user-score").text(res);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form> 
  <input class="js-question-score" name="first" min="0" max="20"  value="0" type="number"/>
  <input class="js-question-score" name="second" min="0" max="20"  value="0" type="number"/>
  <input class="js-question-score" name="third" min="0" max="20"  value="0" type="number"/>
</form>

<div>
  User total score:
  <span class="js-total-user-score">
    0
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: An improvement would be to avoid searching `$(".js-question-score")` inside the change event by wrapping the `this` as a jQuery object like so `$(this)`. This way we would benefit from not traversing the DOM twice.

Comment: @n0m4d Nop because `$(this)` match only the selected element.

Comment: You are definitely right! I completely overlooked that. Thanks for pointing that out =)

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, your code looks alright. You could try to make it more compact but that will not make it more performant. In any case, and for a better understanding of what is going on with your code, I suggest you create a `jsfiddle` and share the link. One thing I could propose is to encapsulate your code, this will make it more readable and easier to maintain, something along the lines of this:

```
var scoreSystem = {

    init: function () {
        this.totalScore = 0;
        $('.js-question-score').change(function () {
            scoreSystem.totalScore();
            scoreSystem.updateScore();
        });
    },

    totalScore: function () {
        $('.js-question-score').each(function() {
            scoreSystem.totalScore += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
    },

    updateScore: function () {
        $('.js-total-user-score').text(scoreSystem.totalScore);
    }
};

$(function() {
    scoreSystem.init();
});
```

In terms of the delay you mention, can you elaborate? - Again, `jsfiddle` would be perfect for reviewing the problem.

Comment: Thx for encapsulation advice! I will try it. As for `jsfiddle`, i used `code Snippet` in my op post, isnt thats the same? I mean when i click "run code snippet" i see environment very similar ro `jsfiddle`. As for delay: when i change input value with clicking on arrows quickly, it takes about 1 sec to change result field. Mb thats the problem with my chromium and you dont see it..

Comment: JSFiddle is an online service where we can see your entire code and test it like a real app. In any case, I am glad I was able to help!

Comment: `scoreSystem` in closure is very very bad practice. why you use `this.totalScore` but `scoreSystem.totalScore` at the same time?

Comment: @Maxx - How is it `very very bad` practice? - `this.totalScore` (yes, it can also be `scoreSystem.totalScore` right away) in the first place is due to the scope, since the other calls are inside functions, the scope of `this` does not exist anymore, hence the object call.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide your functions from the rest of the page, you should enclose them in an anonymous function. It works like this:

```
(function() {
  // your functions and code here
})();
```

Applied to your code, it is:

```
(function() {
    $('.js-question-score').change(function () {
        var totalScore = getTotalUserScore();
        updateTotalUserScore(totalScore);
    });

    function updateTotalUserScore(totalScore) {
        $('.js-total-user-score').text(totalScore)
    }

    function getTotalUserScore() {
        var totalScore = 0;
        $('.js-question-score').each(function() {
            totalScore += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        return totalScore;
    }
})();
```

This has the effect that the functions `updateTotalUserScore` and `getTotalUserScore` are not visible to any other code on the page.

This style is easier to understand than the one suggested in another answer, where you have this structure:

```
var myFunctions = {
    getTotalUserScore: function() { ... },
    change: function() { myFunctions.getTotalUserScore(...); }
};
```

Oh, and by the way, never use `parseInt(num)`, always use `parseInt(num, 10)`. Because in the first form, the number `08` (which may appear in dates) [leads to an error](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Obtain a local copy of this for your server, This is nit picky, but better IMHO.

```
/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js
```

Comment: Unless you have your application fronted by a CDN, I would guess end user is going to typically get better download performance from Google's CDN.